# Do all the haunts in Betrayal at House on the Hill follow a pattern?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

So, I've recently received Betrayal at House on the Hill, and I'm smitten. I'm also learning Java in my spare time. I thought it would be pretty cool to team up with my friend, who's had more experience with this, and make a very similar game in Java.

The issue we have is that we don't know all of the Haunts yet, so we can't program them either. My though was that all of the Haunts follow one of a set of patterns we could emulate:

1. Find items before X happens
2. Find items AND do Y before X happens
3. Kill Monsters X (and/or y)
4. Kill Monster X with Weapon Y
5. Destroy item

Granted I haven't played more than a handful of haunts, but they all seem to play along a pattern.

Is there a full list of all the ways haunts play out?

Comment: I think a *full* list might in some ways spoil things as much as reading through the haunts yourself...

Comment: @Jefromi if it's not much more than this, then it shouldn't. If it *is* much more, I agree.

Comment: I've also seen "Kill Monsters X (and/or Y) before Z happens."  (Still very similar to what you already have, of course.)

Comment: This is a little tough to answer without spoilers, but to put it simply, there are a lot of haunts with hero win conditions that are *similar* to the ones you mentioned, but subtly different, or where the lose condition varies, and some where it doesn't fit your options. The nature of Betrayal is that each haunt *does* change the rules of the game in a unique manner, and so after basic functionality the program would have to be deal with haunts on a per-case basis.

Comment: @Samthere that would make a fine answer!

Comment: @Pureferret I'll write up a proper answer when I can get to my haunt books and look through the ones I've played for reference :D

Comment: @Samthere: I quoted your answer, comment on it if you add your solution.

Answer (score 3):

> This is a little tough to answer without spoilers, but to put it simply, there are a lot of haunts with hero win conditions that are similar to the ones you mentioned, but subtly different, or where the lose condition varies, and some where it doesn't fit your options.
>
> The nature of Betrayal is that each haunt does change the rules of the game in a unique manner, and so after basic functionality the program would have to be deal with haunts on a per-case basis.

Answer by proxy for Samthere's comment. Comment if he posts his own answer and I will delete.